# Why is UAC required on Major Upgrade if component doesn't change?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a burn bundle that includes a perUser package and perMachine package. The perMachine package adds just one firewall exception that requires UAC.

I understand that UAC is required when the firewall exception is added on initial installation, but why is it required on a Major Upgrade if the only components that have changed are in the perUser package? Why doesn't the installation recognise that the perMachine component is already installed and just skip over it with no UAC?

I've tried changing MajorUpgrade to `Schedule="afterInstallExecute"` but this has no effect on the UAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A per-machine package requires elevation. Major-upgrade packages can be completely different from each other, so MSI doesn't break it down to the level of individual components requiring upgrade. If you want to avoid another UAC prompt, you can use [UAC patching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).